# How to hit URL with parameters within an API

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

How to pass parameters to an url for get request in python?

Suppose this is my url:

```
url = "http://105.119.2.20/data/personal/get/Id/<Id>/empId/<empId>/org_id/<orgId>"
```

I have to pass three parameters to this url:

1. Id
2. empId
3. orgId

I want to know how would be the syntax of passing paramaters to hit this url. Whether to pass through dictionary or by variable?

```
r = request.get(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use f-string to format your url just like this

```
    Id = 12
    empId = 123
    orgId = 1234

    url = f'http://105.119.2.20/data/personal/get/Id/{Id}/empId/{empId}/org_id/{orgId}'

    r = request.get(url)
```

Comment: I was passing variables in to the url  "http://105.119.2.20/data/personal/get/Id/{Id}/empId/{empId}/org_id/{orgId}" I don't know why it is not hitting the url and even not giving any error.  And how do we know that our Api is hitting hitting this url or just skipping.

Comment: check the status code of the response using r.status_code

Answer (score 1):

Just pass it as a `dict` to `params` arg

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://example.com/some/api/blah", params={"id": 1, "empId": 2, "orgId": 3})
```

Comment: I was passing variables in to the url  "http://105.119.2.20/data/personal/get/Id/{Id}/empId/{empId}/org_id/{orgId}" I don't know why it is not hitting the url and even not giving any error.  And how do we know that our Api is hitting hitting this url or just skipping.